# php code to insert row of data populated from a mysql database into other mysql database after modification

Tags: php

I am trying to make an attendance sheet. In my code I retrieve the names from a existing database and populate in a html table with the attendance select dropdown. After populating the dropdown all the data in the html table automatically saved into the new database without selecting the submit button. moreover the attendance status shows null value in the database, but the other fields are saved successfully. Please go through my code and give your valuable suggestions to rectify the problem.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="f1" method="POST" ACTION="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">


//call from the previous php page
    <?  $back_page ="recordentry.php";
    $date=$_POST['date'];
$course=$_POST['course'];
$period=$_POST['period'];
$batch=$_POST['batch'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
if(empty($_POST['other']))
{
$faculty=$_POST['faculty'];
}
else

{
    $faculty=$_POST['other'];
}
?>
<p>Current Date & Time : <? echo $date ?></p>

<?

$db="contact";
//mysql_connect(localhost,$_POST['username'],$_POST['pass']);
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (! $link)
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

mysql_select_db($db , $link)
or die("Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error());


$result=mysql_query("SELECT name,uic FROM student where batch='$batch' AND course='$course' order by name")
or die("SELECT ERROR: ".mysql_error());
$userinfo = array();
echo "<table border='1' align='center'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Unique Identification Code</th><th>Attendance(select only the Absentees)</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
//Display the results in different cells

echo "<tr><td align=center>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td align=center>" . $row['uic'] . "</td><td align=center><select name='attendance' style='background-color:#FFC'>
      <option>Present
       <option>Absent
       </select></td></tr>";
//$userinfo = array('name' => $row['name'], 'uic' => $row['uic'], 'attendance' => $row['attendance']);
$row_name=$row['name'];
$row_uic=$row['uic'];
$row_attn=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attendance']);
$userinfo[] = array("name"=> $row_name , "uic"=> $row_uic, "a_status"=> $row_attn);
}
//echo"<tr><td><input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit_button' />";
echo"</table>";

mysql_close($link);
  //form HAS been submitted
?>


<table align="center">
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitbtn" ></td><td><input type="reset" value="reset"></td></tr>
</table>


</form>

<?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{

 foreach ($userinfo as $value)

 {
$name = $value[name];  
 $uic = $value[uic];  
 $a_status = $value[a_status];

$db="contact";
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
//$link = mysql_connect("localhost",$_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
if (! $link)
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db , $link) or die("Select Error: ".mysql_error());

$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO attendance(date, course, period, batch, subject, faculty, name, uic, attendance) VALUES 
('$date', '$course', '$period', '$batch', '$subject', '$faculty', '$name', '$uic', '$a_status')")
  or die("Insert Error: ".mysql_error());

mysql_close($link);

  }

}
?>
```

all the data except attendance save to the database successfully. attendance gives null value. Again, data save before clicking submit button. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but where you write:

```
$a_status = $value[a_status];
```

should surely be

```
$a_status = $value['a_status'];
```

Also, your html is:

```
<select name='attendance' style='background-color:#FFC'>
    <option>Present
    <option>Absent
</select>
```

But it should be:

```
<select name='attendance' style='background-color:#FFC'>
    <option value="present">Present</option>
    <option value="absent">Absent</option>
</select>
```

When using a select box, the 'value' attribute is the value that will be in the $_POST['attendance'], Not the values inside the 'option' tag.

Also, this code is insecure, as it uses SQL injection.

Also, you could possibly send the form to a different page for your POST logic. Combining the two in one file can get confusing.

One file to read the db and output the data.

One file to process the form logic and insert the data.

send the post data to the separate file using:

```
<form action="/path/to/file.php"></form>
```

Also you should put your database connection inside a function like:

```
function db_connect()
{
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    if (! $link)
        die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

    mysql_select_db($db , $link)
        or die("Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error());

    return $link;
}
```

and use it like so:

```
$db_handle = db_connect();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM student", $db_handle);
```

This is so you're not repeating the same code OVER AND OVER again

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I guess the problem is this:

```
$name = $value[name];
$uic = $value[uic];
$a_status = $value[a_status];
```

You should accessing the values of your array like this:

```
$name = $value['name'];
$uic = $value['uic'];
$a_status = $value['a_status'];
```